# Azure Site Extension xdt transform order

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have my own Azure App Service Site Extension, which has an xdt transform that conflicts with another 3rd-party Site Extension. Is there any way to determine the order in which xdt transforms are applied, and can I control the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is the directory order (Directory.GetDirectories).

Here the link to the question on git:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/3157

Answer (score 1):

In your app service go to D:\home\LogFiles\Transform to see the transform logs. See the application.config before and after transformation to verify if your transform is as expected. Following are steps to find the applicationhost.config. You can disable and enable extensions to further debug the sequence of transformation. Click [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Site-Extensions) to read details about Site extensions.

- Go to the Kudu Console
- Click the 'planet' icon
- Click the Config folder
- Click the download button for applicationhost.config. Or you
  can click the Edit button to look at it directly in the browser

Comment: It is good information, but not an answer to the question I asked.

Comment: Are you able to see the logs? Logs should tell you the sequence of the transformations and then you can disable one to see if the other works.

Comment: Good point. Yes, it is possible to know the order in this way.